# Neuronal Network for 10 inputs and 10 outputs

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, regression

I've got a physical problem: To construct a product 10 output parameters (width, length, material, etc.) are determined based on 10 input parameters (performance, temprature, capacity, etc..). The output parameters are obviously depended from the input parameters. But I don't know how. For example output parameter O1 could be dependend from input parameters I1, I2 and I3.

I've got the data of lets say 30k products with their input/output parameters. The data base looks like this:

```
----------------------------------------------
| Product| I1 | I2 | I3 | ... | O1 | O2 | 03 |
----------------------------------------------
| Prod A | 1.2| 2.3| 4.2| ... | 5.3| 6.2| 1.2|
----------------------------------------------
| Prod B | 2.3| 4.1| 1.2| ... | 8.2| 5.2| 5.0|
----------------------------------------------
| Prod C | 6.3| 3.7| 9.1| ... | 3.1| 4.1| 7.7|
----------------------------------------------
| ...    |                                   |
----------------------------------------------
```

So what I need to do is to find ouput parameters O 1-O 10 based on input parameters I 1 - I 10.

**First Question**: If I get it right, this is a regression problem, based on some input values I want to find some output values (in the data there is somewhere a function/formular to determin the correct values). Is this correct?

My idea is to use/train a neuronal network (using keras and tensorflow as backend)

**How would such a neuronal network look like? What is the best practice?**

This is what I have so far:
Input layer with 10 inputs, two full connected deep layers with 100 neurones and an layer with 10 outputs. In keras this looks like this:

```
def baseline_model(self, callback):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=10, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(100, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(10))

    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=["accuracy"])
    model.fit(input_train, output_train, batch_size=5, epochs=2000, verbose=2, callbacks=[callback], shuffle=True, validation_data=(input_val,output_val))

    scores = model.evaluate(input_val, output_val, verbose=1)
    print("Scores:",scores)
```

Of course the model does not work like expected, thats why I'm asking for help... the training failes:

```
Epoch 1999/2000
7s - loss: 47634520366153.6016 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 9585392308285.4395 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
```

**Any suggestions what I should change?** I thought about using "sigmoid" as activation and to normalize the Data to [0,1].

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 2):

> If I get it right, this is a regression problem, based on some input values I want to find some output values

Yes, i think you are right.

> How would such a neuronal network look like? What is the best practice?

It's very broad question. i think you should split your data into train and validation set, start from simplest network (maybe no hidden layer or only one hidden layer) and then make it more and more complicated (add more layers and hidden units) while your validaton error decreases. When your net become quite deep it's good idea to add Batch Normalization layers between your dense layers. You can also look at residual connections but not sure that you really need this.

> Any suggestions what I should change? I thought about using "sigmoid" as activation and to normalize the Data to [0,1].

- Activation function type depends on your outputs type. For categorical outputs sigmoid/softmax probably good choice, linear should be ok for floating numbers.
- Also if one of your inputs is categorial (material type, for example) maybe it's better to split it into several binary inputs.
- It's almost always good idea to normalize your inputs and **outputs**. Non normalized data could really hurt training process.
- Plot error and check how it changes during time. `loss: 47634520366153.6016` is really big but it tell us not so much about optimization. If it decreases maybe you can increase learning rate. If it grows try to decrease learning rate or try another optimization algorithm.
- Check your gradients, if it too big try to use gradient clipping.
- Also try to start from simple model. Maybe from linear regression.

Strongly speaking neural neutwork debugging is big and complicated field, and i am not sure that it's appropriate for stackoverflow discussion

PS Sorry for my English

Answer (score 1):

As @Dark_davier has already said, this is a field where you need some experience. Is not really possible to answer without really doing some tests. But as guideline be careful with the size of your network. In your network you have roughly (some more) 10e4 parameters, and you said you have "only" 30k observations. So there is a high probability of overfitting... So you need to be careful. You would need to use more sophisticated techniques to avoid it (first cross validation to check, then possibly regularisation). But this require some experience in NN optimisation...